# How do I undo git push --all from a me50 created repo?

Tags: git, github, cs50

I am using me50 bot on Github to submit my CS50 course projects and in starting a new branch for my next project, I used this command:

```
git push origin --all
```

This ended up causing me to lose all prior commits on my activity feed and the new project repo is set to default. My other projects still have their commits listed on Github but the activity feed no longer picks them up. What can I do to fix this? Is it a matter of changing the default branch? and if so how can I do that with a repo me50 bot created?

This is quite a niche case as I have not seen any solutions online, I tried resetting HEAD~1 on the new repo but obviously, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Github activity feed only follows commits to the default branch. And me50 switches the "default" branch to the most recent repo. So the push command didn't break anything.

Comment: Hi Ali. Welcome :) This additional information would be better placed in the comment section of your question, or better yet including this in the question by editing it.

Comment: @tjheslin1: this is the answer, not additional information. (This is a self-answered question, [which is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for clarifying; my bad :)